# How to add predefined validators in js

Tags: angularjs

Concerning angular 1.3 .

You can simply add validator to input in html like

```
 `<input type="text" ng-model="vm.variable" name="myVar" minlength="3" required="true"/>`
```

But, how can I add predefined (minlength, maxlenght, required) validators to ngModel programmatically/manually in js?.

EDIT:

```
//I can add custom validator
vm.ngModelCtrl.$validators.customValidator = function () {
    return true
};

//but how to add minlength, or required?
vm.ngModelCtrl.$validators.minlength;
vm.ngModelCtrl.$validators.required;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// inside controller
$scope.minLength = 3

<!-- html --?
<input minlength="{{minLength}}">
```

Or you could write a custom directive.

Comment: I don't wont to use HTML. I need to use js only

Comment: why not use html? In any case, you can put html templates in directives.